# How to determine the total vaccinated citizens given the number of 1st and 2nd dose administered?

Tags: arithmetic, covid-19

Currently, there are 80,918 first COVID-19 vaccine doses and 52,949 vaccines that have been administered in my city. I am interested in looking at the total citizens who are either fully vaccinated or received at least one vaccine.

So, 80,918 (1st dose) + 52,949 (2nd dose) = 133,867 individuals who are either fully vaccinated or received at least one vaccine? **Am I interpreting this right?**

Comment: No, in order to get the second dose you must first get the first dose, so there are max 80918 vaccinated (once or more).

Comment: @user2974951, I see. So, let me clarify, 52,949 (2nd dose) + 27,969 (1st dose without 2nd dose) = 80,918 total individuals who are either fully vaccinated or received at least one vaccine? By the way, thank you for the response.

Comment: Or you can do it the quick way and just look at how many got a first dose. Everyone who has *at least one dose* has to have a first dose and everyone who has a first dose has at least one dose.

Comment: These figures are *extremely* ambiguous.  I would guess your interpretation is correct that "1st Dose" and "2nd Dose" subpopulations are *mutually exclusive* and that the "60%" figure reflects 80918 of a *target* of 134840 and the "39%" figure reflects 52949 of the same target, for a total of 133867 = 60+39 = 99% of the target.  There are at least seven other reasonable interpretations, but this is the only one that is consistent with all the figures shown.  cc @glen_b

Comment: Every set of figures on vaccinations for covid that I've seen has worked this way (i.e. "first dose" means "has had a first dose" rather than "has had exactly one dose") but you're right, there's almost certainly some exceptions to that to be found in some places. It's possible this is one.